# Document upload from iCloud not working Alamofire Multipart

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, icloud-drive

I am trying to upload a document from iCloud using Alamofire multipart but its not working. API is working correctly as I have tested on Postman. Document selection is successful and URL is also being generated correctly but I am getting "Invalid value around character 0" error. Here is my code:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {

    for url in urls{
    let mimeType = mimeTypeForPath(path: url)
    let header = ["Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8", "Authorization": token]
    let postUrl = serverURL + "transaction/upload-document/\(self.currentTransaction.uuid)"
        let URL = try! URLRequest(url: postUrl, method: .post, headers: header)
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in

        var newImage = Data()
        do{
            newImage = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        }catch{
            print("FILE NOT FOUND")
        }
        MultipartFormData.append(newImage, withName: "transactiondocument" , fileName: "transactiondocument" , mimeType: mimeType)

    }, with: URL, encodingCompletion: {
        EncodingResult in
        switch EncodingResult{
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint("SUCCESS RESPONSE: \(response)")
                self.viewDidLoad()
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):

            print("ERROR RESPONSE: \(encodingError)")

        } })
    }
}
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 \"Invalid value around character 0.\" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))"
```

Comment: That error indicates you're getting a non-JSON response, likely an error HTML page. I suggest you print the response properties to see what it was.